# Running Multiple Instances of an Excel Extension C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop

I am having issues running my excel extension in more then one simultaneous instance. An example is launching the first instance of Excel I am able to interact with the extension as expected. Upon launching a second instance of Excel with the first Excel open they begin sharing state such as property values and click events. Also this happens even when just running a build of the auto generated code snippets that Visual Studio makes for Excel Extension development

Does anyone have a suggestion to allow simultaneous instances of my extension to exist.

Comment: Do you use separate Excel Application objects or just one? For example, do you have: `Excel.Application oExcelApp1 = new Excel.ApplicationClass();` and the same for `oExcelApp2` or do you just use one such object?

Comment: I use a Global Excel Application that is created automatically. this is a ribbon extension so it should run on the host excel process but it does not for some reason.